# Grease Pencil has pixelated strokes. Anti-aliasing issue?

Tags: grease-pencil, antialiasing

New Blender user. Using for 2D animation.

Grease Pencil strokes have pixelated edges both in program and when rendered.

Previous searches indicate that anti-aliasing for grease pencil has been removed to be updated at present.

Can anyone confirm, report similar or solve?

Thanks.

Comment: The Grease pencil will be refactored in V2.83 (currently in alpha). More information :  https://code.blender.org/2020/02/grease-pencil-refactor/

Comment: Brush Settings>Advanced>Hardness . reducing this to about 0.9 makes it look a lot better for me

Answer (score 0):

Confirmed. I made a report about it -> https://developer.blender.org/T74938. It seems to be due to the fact that the actual antialiasing system isn't sensitive enough to detect all edges, and therefore antialias some strokes.